# Studio Pre-Amp with Low Noise Floor

Tags: studio, pre-amp, foley, recommendations, gear

Can anyone recommend a studio pre-amp with a low noise floor for recording foley? Don't worry about the $$$$££££, maybe just best in each price bracket!

Edit: I'll mainly be using it with a Neumann KMR-81i or a 416.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few that I know are low noise, there first 2 are often used in Foley:

John Hardy M1: http://www.johnhardyco.com/M-1details.html

Milennia HV3: http://www.mil-media.com/hv-3c.html

True Systems: http://www.true-systems.com/

Grace: http://www.gracedesign.com/

Great River: http://www.greatriverelectronics.com/

Comment: I should add, I used Great River pres on the metal scrapes in my metal impacts library.  I will also be using them on a lot of recordings that I'm doing in the next few weeks.  They are very quite, but add color to your recordings, which you might not always want in foley.

Comment: @chuck russom - thanks so much for this, I will check them out!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the Milennia HV-3C as they are quiet, have a flat response and are very reliable.

The stepped gain is useful, as it allows you to match signals more easily if you have to re-record something (provided you remembered to take notes).